# doctrine 2 Or Where condition

Tags: doctrine-orm

i am trying to make a where condition in my doctrine Query;

the condition should be;

return all Sent Messages where:

> ```
> sender = A and receiver = B
> ```
>
> or
>
> B; sender = B and receiver = A

below is my query; only the first condition is being returned from the query.

```
public function getMessageHistory()
    { 
        $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();

        $qb->select(array('u'))
            ->from('Messages\Entity\Messages','u')
            ->where  ('u.senderUserId = :senderId AND u.receiverUserId = :receiverId')
            ->orWhere('u.senderUserId = :receiverId AND u.receiverUserId = :senderId')
            ->setParameter('senderId',(int)$this->getUserId())
            ->setParameter('receiverId',(int)$this->getRecipientId());  

            $query = $qb->getQuery();

            return $data = $query->getArrayResult(); 
    }
```

thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

I would build this way:

```
$qb->select(array('u'))
    ->from('Messages\Entity\Messages','u')
    ->where(
        $qb->expr()->orX(
            $qb->expr()->andX(
                $qb->expr()->eq( 'u.senderUserId', ':senderId' ),
                $qb->expr()->eq( 'u.receiverUserId', ':receiverId' )
            ),
            $qb->expr()->andX(
                $qb->expr()->eq( 'u.senderUserId', ':receiverId' ),
                $qb->expr()->eq( 'u.receiverUserId', ':senderId' )
            ),
        )
    )
    ->setParameter('senderId',(int)$this->getUserId())
    ->setParameter('receiverId',(int)$this->getRecipientId());
```

Comment: hello Illuisaznar . thank you so much for your reply. i dont know how to use this style  $qb->expr()->orX() . what is it called?i mean, i cannot find anything on doctrine website about how to use it?. do you know any tutorials on it

Comment: Check the [QueryBuilder](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html) reference